# Member's destructor calling from default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, destructor

```
class Part
{
public:
    ~Part() = delete;
};

class CL
{
public:
    CL(){} //error: deleted destructor call
    ~CL();
    Part part;
};

int main()
{
}
```

This code gives an error associated with a `Part`'s deleted destructor call. What is context in default constructor for members destructor calling?

P.S: As I know, destructor for a `Part` member must be called in `~CL()`, but it is specially not defined for demonstrating, that default constructor forces it anywhere

Comment: _"What is context in default constructor for members destructor calling?
c++ constructor destructor delete-operator "_ `Part part;` of course. And it's not really the context of the default constructor.

Comment: Why is `Part::~Part()` deleted?

Comment: if I comment "CL(){}", the code compiles fine. Apparently, this is the case in default ctor

Comment: "Apparently, this is the case in default ctor" no it is not, it is called from `~CL()`

Comment: Is this question about why the error is occurring at all or about why the compiler has this error about the `CL::CL()` definition?

Comment: @Kevin _"... or about why the compiler has this error ..."_ In that case the specific compiler should be mentioned in the question or the tags.

Comment: Is this related to the fact that constructors have to destroy the initialized members in case of exception?

Comment: I has updated example, and the error happens without any local objects. P.S: This is simplified example, the real problem is more complex

Comment: @user3514538 -- *real problem is more complex* -- Why would it be more complex?  Any compiler error can be duplicated with at most, a couple of dummy classes and a few lines of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, this is just that example with dummy classes :)

Comment: Not any action the language allows you is logical.

Comment: FWIW making the constructor `noexcept` has no effect while making it `= default` removes the error. Tested with gcc 7.2 and VS2015.

Comment: @user3514538 [Well, I see what you mean](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9911ff72275c9c7).

Comment: Perhaps this question needs the language lawyer tag.

Comment: It seems that I know the reason of error: if constructor throws an exception, the destructors of all members must be called, so they (destructors) must be callable

Comment: at class `CL` compile time, the compiler registers the constructors and destructors of the class member variables, and since `~Part()=delete` then it cannot create the class `CL` because it doesn't know how to destroy it, or more precisely **its destruction is incomplete**

Comment: @user3514538 I mentioned that in an earlier comment. However, if that's actually the case, why does `CL() = default;` compile fine, even if you change `Part`'s constructor to `Part() noexcept(false) {};`?

Comment: @François Andrieux, ops, I did not notice that, but anyway, the reason is not in exceptions, in this case

Comment: @user3514538 It looks like `CL() = default;` actually deletes `CL::CL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every constructor needs to have access to it's members' destructors. When a constructor throws an exception, it must be able to destroy every member that was initialized before the exception was thrown. You can verify that this is true for every constructor. If you try adding arbitrary arguments to the constructor, the error still occurs, even with copy and move constructors.

As it was mentioned in the comments, `CL() = default;` doesn't produce the error. This is because `CL() = default;` simply causes the compiler to produce the implicit default constructor it would normally generate. In this case, it appears the CL has a [deleted implicitly-declared default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor), meaning the automatically generated implicit default constructor would be deleted. If you try the following, you see that the default constructor is not actually available :

```
#include <type_traits>

class Part
{
public:
    ~Part() = delete;
};

class CL
{
public:
    CL() = default;
    ~CL();
    Part part;
};

// This assert passes
static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<CL>::value == false, "");
```

However, I can't explain precisely *why* CL has a deleted implicitly-declared default constructor, nor can I explain why `CL() noexcept {};` doesn't work.

Comment: CL has a deleted constructor because of [special]/4: having a potentially constructed subobject with inaccessible/deleted destructor

Answer (score 1):

First, `Part` is a *potentially constructed subobject* of `CL` according to [[special]p5](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/special#5).

> For a class, its non-static data members, its non-virtual direct base classes, and, if the class is not abstract, its virtual base classes are called its *potentially constructed subobjects*.

So the destructor for `Part` is *potentially invoked* according to [[class.base.init]p12](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/special#class.base.init-12), regardless of the existence of `nonexcept` or not.

> In a non-delegating constructor, the destructor for each potentially constructed subobject of class type is potentially invoked.

Therefore the program is ill-formed according to [[class.dtor]p12](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#12).

> A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the invocation.

Note even though the deleted destructor is not actually invoked, the program is ill-formed as long as the destructor is **potentially** invoked.

Comment: Regarding the final paragraph, *potentially invoked* is a somewhat academic term, since there is no actual way that calling this particular constructor would invoke the destructor